# Datepicker not shows date,it shows both date and time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the code I have but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#QuoteDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
}
```

`QuoteDate` is id of datepicker.

Comment: *it's not working* is ***NOT*** a very precise description and not helpful at all - **WHAT** is not working? You cannot select dates? You get an error - if so, **what** error? Or what else is "not working" ..... please be more helpful and more precise!

Comment: you should use **datetimepicker** rather than **datepicker**.

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? [jQuery ui datepikcer](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? [fengyuanchen datepicker](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap **Datepicker** then use following code.

```
  $("#QuoteDate").datepicker({
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
   });
```